# Issue running Gradle build with SonarQube plugin

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I'm trying to fail my Gradle build in case of critical or blocker warning reported by Sonar.

I have a buildscript section with sonar gradle plugin :

```groovy
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3'
    }
}
```

I apply the sonarqube plugin among the other plugins:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

I have a sonarqube section with properties :

```groovy
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.host.url', 'http://some.host:8743'
        property 'sonar.projectKey', 'some-project'
        property 'sonar.login', '${env.SONAR_TOKEN}'
        property 'sonar.qualitygate.wait', 'true'
    }
}
```

I run sonarqube after unit tests :

```groovy
tasks.withType(Test) {
    finalizedBy 'sonarqube'
}
```

And I have such issue :

```
org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

My project must build on JDK8. Upgrading it to JDK11 is not an option (it’s a vendor constraint, we don’t get to choose the JDK to use).
What can I do to make my build work ?

I would hate to split the build in two (1 JDK8 build for compilation & tests + 1 JDK11 build just for Sonar) because that would mean first build can succeed and the other fail.

I'm using SonarQube Community Edition Version 9.8 (build 63668).

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use [CLI-version of SonarScanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner/) on a separate stage (with different Java version) of your CI pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Adding below in gradle.properties of .gradle directory

org.gradle.java.home=/java directory location

or add below in build.gradle

compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/javac_location'

Let me know if it worked. Thanks